# hibernate parent loop to fetch children

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hello I have an app using Hibernate/JPA and Spring Data.
I have 2 entities with a parent child relationship with one to many relationship.
They are below:

this is the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dataset")
public class Dataset {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "guid", nullable = false)
    private String guid;
    @Column(name = "size", nullable = false)
    private Long size;
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    private Date createTime;
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    private User createdBy;
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private boolean active;
    @Column(name = "orig_source", nullable = false)
    private String origSource;
    @Column(name = "orig_source_type", nullable = false)
    private String origSourceType;
    @Column(name = "orig_source_org", nullable = false)
    private String origSourceOrg;
    @Column(name = "uri", nullable = false)
    private String uri;
    @Column(name = "mimetype", nullable = false)
    private String mimetype;
    @Column(name = "registration_state", nullable = false)
    private int registrationState;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<DatasetFile> datasetFiles;
    ...
}
```

and this is the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dataset_file")
public class DatasetFile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "filename", nullable = false)
    private String filename;
    @Column(name = "filesize", nullable = false)
    private Long filesize;
    @Column(name = "location", nullable = false)
    private String uri;
    @Column(name = "alias", nullable = false)
    private String alias;
    @Column(name = "guid", nullable = false)
    private String guid;
    @Column(name = "mimetype", nullable = false)
    private String mimetype;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Dataset dataset;
```

The following is the Spring Data repository I created:

```
public interface DatasetRepo extends JpaRepository<Dataset, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(p) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM Dataset p WHERE p.uri = ?1")
    public Boolean existsByURI(String location);
}
```

When I call the repository's `findAll()` method I'm noticing that Hibernate first fetches all the parents, then loops through each parent and runs a query per parent to fetch the children, I can't imagine that Hibernate doesn't know to just run 1 query to fetch the parents and the children all in one fell swoop and unmarshall the record set accordingly.

below is the snippet from the log (annotated with my own comments)

```
//this is where it fetches the data set
Hibernate: select dataset0_.id as id1_1_, dataset0_.active as active2_1_, dataset0_.create_time as create_t3_1_, dataset0_.created_by as created13_1_, dataset0_.guid as guid4_1_, dataset0_.mimetype as mimetype5_1_, dataset0_.name as name6_1_, dataset0_.orig_source as orig_sou7_1_, dataset0_.orig_source_org as orig_sou8_1_, dataset0_.orig_source_type as orig_sou9_1_, dataset0_.registration_state as registr10_1_, dataset0_.size as size11_1_, dataset0_.uri as uri12_1_ from dataset dataset0_

//this is where it fetches the create user
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_5_1_, user0_.active as active2_5_1_, user0_.fn as fn3_5_1_, user0_.home_div as home_div4_5_1_, user0_.ln as ln5_5_1_, user0_.mi as mi6_5_1_, user0_.password as password7_5_1_, user0_.username as username8_5_1_, authoritie1_.id_user as id_user1_5_3_, authority2_.id as id_autho2_6_3_, authority2_.id as id1_0_0_, authority2_.name as name2_0_0_ from user user0_ left outer join users_authority authoritie1_ on user0_.id=authoritie1_.id_user left outer join authority authority2_ on authoritie1_.id_authority=authority2_.id where user0_.id=?

//this is where it fetch dataset files
Hibernate: select datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_1_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_0_, datasetfil0_.alias as alias2_2_0_, datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filename as filename3_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filesize as filesize4_2_0_, datasetfil0_.guid as guid5_2_0_, datasetfil0_.mimetype as mimetype6_2_0_, datasetfil0_.location as location7_2_0_ from dataset_file datasetfil0_ where datasetfil0_.dataset_id=?
    Hibernate: select datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_1_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_0_, datasetfil0_.alias as alias2_2_0_, datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filename as filename3_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filesize as filesize4_2_0_, datasetfil0_.guid as guid5_2_0_, datasetfil0_.mimetype as mimetype6_2_0_, datasetfil0_.location as location7_2_0_ from dataset_file datasetfil0_ where datasetfil0_.dataset_id=?
    Hibernate: select datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_1_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_0_, datasetfil0_.alias as alias2_2_0_, datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filename as filename3_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filesize as filesize4_2_0_, datasetfil0_.guid as guid5_2_0_, datasetfil0_.mimetype as mimetype6_2_0_, datasetfil0_.location as location7_2_0_ from dataset_file datasetfil0_ where datasetfil0_.dataset_id=?
    Hibernate: select datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_1_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_0_, datasetfil0_.alias as alias2_2_0_, datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filename as filename3_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filesize as filesize4_2_0_, datasetfil0_.guid as guid5_2_0_, datasetfil0_.mimetype as mimetype6_2_0_, datasetfil0_.location as location7_2_0_ from dataset_file datasetfil0_ where datasetfil0_.dataset_id=?
    Hibernate: select datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_1_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_1_, datasetfil0_.id as id1_2_0_, datasetfil0_.alias as alias2_2_0_, datasetfil0_.dataset_id as dataset_8_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filename as filename3_2_0_, datasetfil0_.filesize as filesize4_2_0_, datasetfil0_.guid as guid5_2_0_, datasetfil0_.mimetype as mimetype6_2_0_, datasetfil0_.location as location7_2_0_ from dataset_file datasetfil0_ where datasetfil0_.dataset_id=?
...
```

Any idea how to help Hibernate to smarter about these queries?  (If I were to write this in raw SQL I'd join the dataset, user, and dataset_file all in one query, it's many times faster.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using eager loading your `datasetFiles` so your persistence provider will eagerly fetch load your `datasetFiles` because you set it as `EAGER` fetch strategy. By default, the fetch strategy for `@OneToMany` in JPA is `LAZY`. Just don't set the `fetch` strategy and the persistence provider will LAZY load it for you.

Comment: But I want all the dataset_files to be loaded when I read the datasets, however loading the dataset_files as a loop through the datasets seems very naive to me.  A single join to do this work is magnitudes faster. e.g: select a.*, b.* from dataset a inner join dataset_file b on a.id=b.dataset_id;

Comment: Why do you want to load your dataset_files all at once? Don't forget that by doing LAZY strategy you are hinting the persistence provider that when the collection is required to first load the data before and return the collected entity back to the client.